# jQuery highlight plugin breaks a word with special characters (üöä)

Tags: jquery, encoding, special-characters, highlight

I have a jQuery plugin that on input of word highlights the corresponding value in text. Words can be separated with space too. My problem is when there is a word with special characters (ü,ö or ä). When I enter for example 'dölor' or 'faücibus', the highlight breaks so that it looks like 'd lor' or 'fa cibus'.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbwe4/1/

HTML

```
<body>
  <input type="text" class="span1 disabled" id="field1" name="field1"><br>
  <input type="text" class="span1 disabled" id="field2" name="field2"><br>
  <p>Vestibulum rhoncus urna sed urna euismod, ut cursus erüos molestie.
  Nulla sed ante ut diam gravida auctor eu quis augue.
  Donec egäet diam malesuada, consectetur orci at, ultrices tellus.
  Duis id dui vel sem consequat rütrum eget non orci.
  Nullam sit amet libero odiö. Vestibulum sapien sapien, molestie quis porta nec,
  sodales nec felis. Mauris vehicula, erat eu consectetur viverra,
  dui tellus laoreet dölor, quis faücibus turpis eros non mi.</p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.highlight2, .highlight1 {
  background-color: #fff34d;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  /* FF1+ */
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* Saf3-4 */
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /* FF3.5+ */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /* Opera 10.5+, IE 9.0 */
}
.highlight2, .highlight1 {
  padding:1px 4px;
  margin:0 -4px;
}
.highlight2 {
  background-color: #cecece;
}
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
  $('#field1').bind('keyup change', function (ev) {
    // pull in the new value
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    // remove any old highlighted terms
    $('body').removeHighlight('span.highlight1');
    // disable highlighting if empty
    if (searchTerm) {
      var terms = searchTerm.split(/\W+/);
      $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
        // highlight the new term
        term = term.trim();
        if (term != "") $('body').highlight(term, 'highlight1');
      });
    }
  });
  $('#field2').bind('keyup change', function (ev) {
    // pull in the new value
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    // remove any old highlighted terms
    $('body').removeHighlight(['span.highlight2']);
    // disable highlighting if empty
    if (searchTerm) {
      var terms = searchTerm.split(/\W+/);
      $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
        // highlight the new term
        term = term.trim();
        if (term != "") $('body').highlight(term, 'highlight2');
      });
    }
  });
});

jQuery.fn.highlight = function (pat, className) {
  function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
    var skip = 0;
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
      if (pos >= 0) {
        var spannode = document.createElement('span');
        spannode.className = className || 'highlight';
        var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
        var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
        var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
        spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
        middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
        skip = 1;
      }
    } else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
        i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
      }
    }
    return skip;
  }
  return this.each(function () {
    innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
  });
};

jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function (classNames) {
  function newNormalize(node) {
    for (var i = 0, children = node.childNodes, nodeCount = children.length; i < nodeCount; i++) {
      var child = children[i];
      if (child.nodeType == 1) {
        newNormalize(child);
        continue;
      }
      if (child.nodeType != 3) {
        continue;
      }
      var next = child.nextSibling;
      if (next == null || next.nodeType != 3) {
        continue;
      }
      var combined_text = child.nodeValue + next.nodeValue;
      new_node = node.ownerDocument.createTextNode(combined_text);
      node.insertBefore(new_node, child);
      node.removeChild(child);
      node.removeChild(next);
      i--;
      nodeCount--;
    }
  }
  var selectors = classNames;
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(classNames) === '[object Array]')
    selectors = classNames.join(',');
  return this.find(selectors).each(function () {
    var thisParent = this.parentNode;
    thisParent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
    newNormalize(thisParent);
  }).end();
};
```

There is some kind of encoding problem I suppose. Help anyone? I tried something with insert of jQuery encoding but it didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write `searchTerm.split(/\s+/);` inspite of `searchTerm.split(/\W+/);` everything will work fine.

here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/5ANZG/

\W+ Matches any nonword character, \W is equivalent to [^a-zA-Z_0-9] and doesn't include the unicode categories.

Comment: Love you man! :) thanks, what are the difference between s+ and W+?

Comment: \W+ Matches any nonword character, \W is equivalent to [^a-zA-Z_0-9] and doesn't include the unicode categories. s+ Matches any white-space character